# If let clause when getting from NSUserDefaults()

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, getter

I'm trying to manage a variable like this:

```
var isFinished: Bool {
    get {
      return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFinished")
    }
    set {
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: "isFinished")
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
  }
```

This works, however, I'm trying to make it more safe by using an `if let` when getting:

```
var isFinished: Bool {
    get {
      if let isFinished = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFinished") as? Bool {
        return isFinished
      }
    }
    set {
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(newValue, forKey: "isFinished")
      NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }
  }
```

This will give a yellow error though: *"Conditional cast from 'Bool' to 'Bool' always succeeds."*

Alright then:

```
if let isFinished = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFinished") {
  return isFinished
}
```

Now it's worse: *"Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'"*

What's the correct way of handling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary approach is fine.

`boolForKey` of `NSUserDefaults` doesn't return an optional therefore any optional binding attempt is meaningless.

```
func boolForKey(_ aKey: String) -> Bool
```

> If a Boolean value is associated with the specified key, that value is
>   returned. If the key was not found, this method returns NO.

Comment: I hope they change this, optionals would be perfect for this.

Comment: @TimVermeulen  According Apple's recommendation to register default values for `NSUserDefaults`to have reliable states optionals are actually not needed at all.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this!

Comment: @vadian Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write in this way :-

```
if let isFinished : Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isFinished") 
{
      return isFinished
}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: This will raise the *Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'* error

Comment: Thanks for your answer, N.Raval, I've accepted the other answer since it seems to be Apple's recommendation and people, like me, may not know the way this is actually handled. Because your answer does work indeed, I gave it an upvote.

Comment: @nontomatic Thank you :)